# Why I cannot see WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf

I created the simple WCF Service and configured it like the below

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="CcmDmzService.CcmWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="CCMServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CcmDmzService.ICcmWcfService" 
                  bindingConfiguration="CcmDmzBindingConfig">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8031/TestService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CCMServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CcmDmzBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          openTimeout="00:30:00"
          closeTimeout="00:30:00"
          receiveTimeout="05:00:00"
          sendTimeout="05:00:00">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I run the service, service opens but I cannot see the WSDL(the registered base address must be HTTPS)

Comment: What url you are using to access WSDL? Can you please post it?

Comment: @PankajKapare https://localhost:8031/TestService

Comment: @PankajKapare, I solved it by manually registering that port and sslcertification by "netsh http add sslcert.." and "netsh http add urlacl..." commands.